# Can we use nginx proxy to hide origin server exposure from external smtp like gmail?

Tags: nginx, centos, smtp, proxy, reverse-proxy

So if possible, I'd like to hide the exposure of my origin server ip when sending SMTP emails for example from Gmail because I have been DDoSed several times just because they get IP from email.

I have also Cloudflare, but it is still leaking origin IP.

So is it possible to do something like proxypass or anything to hide the exposure of origin ip? If yes, please help me out.

This is my current setup and using nginx + centos 6.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com www.example.com;
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root /var/www/example.com/html;
        index  index.php;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /var/www/example.com/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/example.com/html$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
```

Comment: Use a third party mailing service such as sendgrid, mandrill, etc.

Comment: I did sendmail and sendgrid, they both leak FQDN and origin IP.    Received: from fqdn.example.com (fqdn.example.com [origin ip]) by mxa.mailgun.org with ESMTP id xxxx-smtp-out-n01; Fri, 08 Mar 2019 20:44:16 -0000 (UTC)

Comment: That's mailgun, not sendgrid, and I did not recommend it

Comment: Here it goes, still adding headers. By the way I'm using mybb forum platform would that the smtp.php code from them be leaking it? Received: from serv3.example.com (serv3.example.com [origin]) by xxx1p1lon1.sendgrid.net (SG) with ESMTP id xxx2pDGS51OoTMA for <mail@gmail.com>; Fri, 08 Mar 2019 21:12:44.376 +0000 (UTC)

Comment: Strange, I've never seen such a header on sendgrid. Maybe there's a setting one of us missed?